# Which verb is used for "charge": 取る or もらう

Tags: usage

On Weblio, I found several example sentences using [いくら取る](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89+charge). However, when I asked a similar question on [HiNative](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/7229968), a native speaker used the verb もらう in his/her answer. I suspect that it had something to do with the verb I used in my question, which was in Mandarin Chinese since I had asked in English earlier and didn't get any reply. In the reply I got, the sentence was:

```
店主は彼にいくらもらった？ How much did the shopkeeper "receive" from your boyfriend?
```

When I saw the reply, I realized that I probably didn't properly convey the idea of "charging money" in my question asked in Chinese on HiNative. Thereafter, I raised another question there:

```
あの屋は君にいくらぐらい取った？ Roughly how much did the shop charge ya?
```

I used the verb 取る according to Google and Weblio, but two native speakers voted "I don't understand" on this sentence. I suspect the problem lies either in a misuse of 屋－which I wrongly thought could represent the owner of a shop－or in the verb 取る itself.

**The Question:**

When speaking about how much someone charges you for something (e.g. a service, a product), which one would be the right verb to use if I were to include the business owner as the subject of the sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What verb is most appropriate to use depends on where ***you*** as a speaker/writer stand in regards to the transaction.  Are you a third person?  Do you belong to the business/store?  Or are you the customer?

Be very careful with a verb like 「**取{と}る**」 when talking about a monetary transaction.  (***In short, do not even use it!***)  It can sound far more greedy, aggressive, impolite, etc. than you seem to think.  「取る」 has the overtone of "to rip off" at least to an extent.

If you are from the business, you would not want any customers to hear you use the verb (so you would use it only with another person from the business).  「取る」 is that negative a word in business.  If you are the customer and you used 「取られる/取られた」, it would sound as if you were unhappy about getting charged more than you should have been.

Since the customer is king in the Japanese-speaking world, however, customers actually can use 「取る/取られる」 in many cases without offending anyone, but if someone from that business/store used it openly, he would offend almost everyone including the other conscientious coworkers.

So, what are the good verbs here?

For the business side, those would be 「頂{いただ}く」、「頂戴{ちょうだい}する」、  「（ご）請求{せいきゅう}する」, etc.

For the customer side, 「支払{しはら}う」、「お支払いする」、「納{おさ}める」, etc.

What words the third parties should use depends on whose standpoint they are speaking from.  In other words, it depends on what the subject of the sentence is.

Thus, a third person would say:

・「店主{てんしゅ}（or そのお店{みせ}）はそのお客{きゃく}さんにいくら**請求した**のですか。」 ***active*** voice

・「そのお客さんはお店にいくら**請求された**のですか。」 ***passive*** voice

「あの屋」 makes no sense, but I will not get into that here.

Comment: Is there any circumstance under which one would use もらう as in the answer I received on HiNative?